# Joining same table with NULL values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple table like

```
user_id | meta_key | meta_value
===============================
   1    | color    | green
   2    | color    | red
   1    | size     | L
   2    | size     | L
   3    | color    | blue

...
```

Now I like a single query where I get all colors and sizes of a certain user

```
SELECT a.user_id AS ID, a.meta_value AS color, b.meta_value AS size
   FROM table AS a
   LEFT JOIN table AS b ON a.user_id = b.user_id 
WHERE a.meta_key = 'color' AND b.meta_key = 'size' GROUP BY a.meta_value, b.meta_value
```

This works as long I have a `size` for each user. If `size` is missing (ID 3 in example) the user isn't in the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The predicate on `b.meta_key` in the **`WHERE`** is negating the "outerness" of the LEFT JOIN operation.

One option is to relocate that predicate to the **`ON`** clause, for example:

```
SELECT a.user_id AS ID, a.meta_value AS color, b.meta_value AS size
   FROM table AS a
   LEFT JOIN table AS b ON a.user_id = b.user_id 
      AND b.meta_key = 'size'
 WHERE a.meta_key = 'color' GROUP BY a.meta_value, b.meta_value
```

---

**FOLLOWUP**

**Q:** What if `color` is missing?

**A:** You'd need a table or inline view as a rowsource that returns every value of `user_id` that you want included in the result set.  For example, if you had a table named "users" with one row per `user_id`, and you want to return every `id` in that table:

```
 SELECT u.id         AS user_id
      , a.meta_value AS color
      , b.meta_value AS size
   FROM user u
   LEFT
   JOIN `table` a
     ON a.user_id = u.id
    AND a.meta_key = 'color'
   LEFT
   JOIN `table` b
     ON b.user_id = u.id
    AND b.meta_key = 'size'
  GROUP
     BY u.id
      , a.meta_value
      , b.meta_value
```

---

We also note that the `GROUP BY` in your original query does not include the `user_id` column, so any rows that have the same `meta_value` for color and size will be collapsed, and you'll get only one of the `user_id` values that have matching color and size.

Note that if the combination of `user_id` and `meta_key` is UNIQUE (in table `table`), then the GROUP BY isn't necessary.

---

In the normative relational model, attributes of an entity are implemented as columns. As a good example, the resultset being returned by the query looks a lot like the table we'd expect.

When an Entity Attribute Value (EAV) model is implemented in a relational database, the SQL gets an order of magnitude more complicated.

---

If you want to return ONLY values of user_id that have either `color` or `size`, you could get a list of user_id values with an inline view (query against `table`). This query is the same as above, but replacing the reference to the `user` table with an inline view:

```
 SELECT u.id         AS user_id
      , a.meta_value AS color
      , b.meta_value AS size
   FROM ( SELECT t.user_id AS id
            FROM table t
           WHERE t.meta_key IN ('color','size')
          GROUP BY t.user_id
        ) u
   LEFT
   JOIN `table` a
     ON a.user_id = u.id
    AND a.meta_key = 'color'
   LEFT
   JOIN `table` b
     ON b.user_id = u.id
    AND b.meta_key = 'size'
  GROUP
     BY u.id
      , a.meta_value
      , b.meta_value
```

Comment: @revaxarts: you'd need a "source" for the `user_id` column, either a table or inline view that is guaranteed to return every value of `user_id` you want returned. I'll update my answer with a followup.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought about the problem when either color nor size exits. In my case I wouldn't need that entry at all so the first answer is right

Answer (score 1):

The where clause is killing you.  Let's take `b.meta_key = 'size'`.  If there are no rows in your B table, meta_key will come back null.  The filter on that column removes them from the result.  Try adding the `b.meta_key = 'size'` to the on clause.

Answer (score 0):

try following code,

```
SELECT a.user_id AS ID, a.meta_value AS color, b.meta_value AS size FROM table AS a where a.meta_key = 'color' or a.meta_key = 'size'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.user_id AS ID,
a.meta_value AS color, b.meta_value AS size
FROM table AS a
LEFT JOIN table AS b ON a.user_id = b.user_id 
WHERE a.meta_key in ('Color', 'Size')
```